# name specific get_meta_tag PHP

Tags: php, html, get, meta-tags

How can I get a specific meta tag from another file in php? This is the code that im using to create my meta tag: `<meta name="thumbnail" content="1.png" />`

This what i've tried in javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementByID('myIdExample').content; 
alert(x);
```

but because the meta tag is in an external page I doesn't work.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Matt I have tried to do this with js but I can't because it is on a different page.

Comment: ***What*** have you tried? Provide some code that shows what you've done so we can see if you're on the right track or not.

Comment: @Matt var x = document.getElementByID('myIdExample').content; alert(x);

Answer (score 0):

if fixed by using `explode()`
replace the `**thumbnail**` with the name of the tag that you would like to use...

```
$thumbnail = get_meta_tags('http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/background-garage/?p=photo&photo=1');
$thumbnail = array_map('trim', explode(',', $thumbnail['**thumbnail**']));
```